# Using an Arduino as a regular AVR

Tags: arduino, avr

I'm planning to do a project using ATmega (I can't use an Arduino directly because of my university's restrictions). But I really want to use the Arduino's IDE, serial monitor, plotting graphs using [Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29) for debugging purposes. Can I dump my regular ATmega code into an Arduino and use serial monitor for debugging purposes?

Can I use an [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) board just like any other normal AVR development board so that I can get the best of both worlds. I googled it, but I didn't get the answer I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean using the Arduino's AVR microcontroller without the Arduino libraries: that's perfectly possible. You're going to have to mess with some lower-level stuff, though. You can get some inspiration from what I have done so far with [libavrutil](http://github.com/H2CO3/libavrutil).

Comment: I'm perfectly fine with the register level programming of atmega.I may just use functions like Serial.begin() from arduino library for using the serial monitor for debugging purpose.Can i directly use my previous avr codes and dump the into uno board using the arduino IDE?

Comment: Wow.Thats very cool.I'm gonna try it now.Thnx for the help :)